# ftp and seek keywords in multithreaded mode

Tags: java, multithreading

I get files from ftp server and search for keywords.

It seems ftp in multithreaded mode and reading files in multithreaded mode both cannot improve performance, but what if searching and ftp next file at the same time? Can I call it multithread? Will it improve performance?

Comment: Do you need all files downloaded to start searching for keywords? Probably not. Will it improve performance to simultaneously download files and process them? Certainly yes.

Comment: 'simultaneously'? I mean searching downloaded file while downloading the next one.  So you just ignore my aproach or misunderstand my words as a result of my poor english.  So i think you prefer to ' simultaneously download files and process them'. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Why your reply is a comment, not a answer?

Comment: As you said above, I don't fully understood your question, so I did not post an answer, because it may be not what you meant. By saying "simultaneously download files and process them" I mean downloading files in one group of threads and processing them in another group - and these two groups should be running next to each other (at one moment). First group downloads files and places completed files in blocking queue. Another group block on queue, and as soon as file becomes available - process it. If it's not what you ask in your question - please improve it.

Comment: Thanks.This time I not only understand your advice, but also know to find some samples by seaching in web by keywords 'blocking quene'. Thanks again.